# whats happening to my simple script?

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash
while read file1; do
     while read file2 : do
    if [ $file1 == $file2 ] ; then
    $file1 >> /infanass/dev/admin/test/newlist.txt
    fi
    echo "$file1"
    echo "$file2"
 done < /infanass/dev/admin/test/file2.txt
done < /infanass/dev/admin/test/file1.txt
```

**Error :**

```
 ./test.bsh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
 ./test.bsh: line 9: `    done 3</infanass/dev/admin/test/file2.txt'
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized since the only error was a simple typo and in any case, this is not a *nix question but a bash one.

Answer (score 3):

On line 3 you have

```
while read file2 : do
```

It should read

```
while read file2 ; do
```

So your while loop's syntax would be valid.

And on a sidenote: since you are using the older `[` and not `[[` you should quote the `file1` and `file2` variables to prevent `pathname expansion` and `word splitting` from breaking your `[` command.

Comment: I am stupid! wow